# footer on the baseline

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I cannot figure out why the black bar on footer doesn't goes on the baseline of the window.
I don't want it "fixed" while scrolling. Just on the absolute bottom

```
html { 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

body {
    padding-top: 15px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
    background: #f7f7f7 repeat-x url(<%=image_path('background.png')%>) top left;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #323232;
}

footer{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;

}
```

[image]

Comment: shouldn't the bottom property and others be 0px instead of 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [very solid solution](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) for this common problem that I always use when I want a footer to be 'sticky'.

Comment: I tried but in other pages, if I scroll down I get this: http://cl.ly/image/2l2I1d0C1i28

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong ;) Please add you HTML and CSS so we can try to see what's going wrong.

Comment: RESOLVED! :) It was "position: absolute;" on footer